# App errors even when its a new empty project

Tags: android, gradle

The app works when I build it in my phone using Android Studio. But when I send it to low sdk device it doesn't work even when its sdk <=14
like Samsung s3 or s2.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pc.zaid.zzz"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Comment: unfortunately the app has been stopped